# inkscape to convert svg -> png: pagesize?

Tags: svg, png, inkscape

I need to convert svg to png at the command-line. I tried using imagemagick but it seems to have a bug when used with rotate transforms, e.g. this sample s3.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="layer1">
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="200" stroke="black"
        stroke-width="0.5" fill="none"/>
    <g transform="rotate(48 200 200)">
      <path id="path00" style="fill:#dca08c;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1"
         d="M 200,0 L 400,200 L 200,400 L 0,200 z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I was able to use inkscape at the command-line:

```
  c:\app\inkscape\portable\App\Inkscape\inkscape.com -f s3.svg -e s3.png --export-background=white --export-area=0:652:400:1052
```

but SVG coordinates (0,0) are defined at the upper left whereas in inkscape's export the export area is (0,0) defined at the lower left.

How can I use inkscape to export without the magic number 1052 that defines the page height?

Comment: I don't know much about InkScape, but the [documentation](http://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html) seems very straight forward

Comment: Imagemagick works on my environment with the same output given by inkscape. Can you give the command line you used ?

Comment: In what way is this a *programming* question?

Comment: The SVG is not from inkscape. I am "programming" (yes, loosely interpreted) drawing images using SVG, and then "programmatically" creating a png image from the svg using inkscape command line. If I can tweak either the SVG or the command line syntax, to get what I need, that will solve my problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to directly access the page size?

Answer (score 3):

One way that might help is to draw an area you want as a container, give it an id, and export that with the `-i id` option. Give the wrapper blank background/border if it shouldn't be visible.

Edit (adding example):
I used this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="layer1">
    <rect width="400" height="600" id="wrapper" fill="none"></rect>
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="200" stroke="black"
        stroke-width="0.5" fill="none"/>
    <g transform="rotate(48 200 200)">
      <path id="path00" style="fill:#dca08c;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1"
         d="M 200,0 L 400,200 L 200,400 L 0,200 z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And with this command (I'm on a mac, so translate specific OS as needed) I could control the size/position of the output png:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape -f test.svg -e out.png -i wrapper
```

I'm not an svg expert so I'm not sure if there are some specific things inkscape does, but I've always found it very web compliant. In the past I've used its svg files directly in web pages.

Comment: image is not from inkscape, can I do this in the xml itself?

Comment: Yeah, I was able to do it with the xml example above, saved to file, and called with: -f test.svg -e out.png -i layer1

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you are trying to export is the whole drawing.

`inkscape` has the option to export the drawing with `--export-area-drawing` instead of specifying the area to export.

```
c:\app\inkscape\portable\App\Inkscape\inkscape.com -f s3.svg -e s3.png --export-background=white --export-area-drawing
```

Comment: +1 for finding that... but I would still like to choose the exact area to export.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not knowing the page height then the following syntax might help?

```
c:\app\inkscape\portable\App\Inkscape\inkscape.com s3.svg -z --query-height
```

This should return the pixel height of the document, you can use the returned number in your export call.

Comment: Nope, it returns the height of the drawing. From `inkscape --help` : `Query the height of the drawing or, if specified, of the object with --query-id`

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape has canvas size option, I had the same problem exporting for the web - your image drops out of the viewport.

Change canvas/artboard size to meet the size of element you are exporting

Comment: SVG is not *from* Inkscape though.

Comment: Can I specify it in the svg xml itself?